# How can I check if wifi is receiving data on android?

Tags: android, connection, wifi

So I've gone through a lot of trouble recently trying to figure out how to check if wifi connection is actually working on Android. I'm aware there are a lot of threads with similar matter around the community, but those mostly approach the issue from **ConnectivityManager** which seemingly is only able to check if there is a WiFi connection stablished and that is not enough.

I've also seen people suggesting **ping/HTTP** checks but I would like to know if there is a way around those methods since that would use any available data.

I intend to run the solution in a service that periodically checks if connection is available and phone is online, although I'm not quite sure if that's a viable way of accomplishing my goals.

**Service:**

```
package com.mattos.murilorm.meavisaquandotiverinternet;


import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends Service{

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Service started!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Service destroyed!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Please help!

Comment: @Lino the code provided is the foundation in which I intend to run any possible solutions for the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way of detecting actual connection quality without sampling some data, so if you don't want to do ping style requests you don't have a lot of options other than a simple check for whether or not you are connected to something.

Facebook made a pretty useful library that will:

> Listen to current network traffic in the app and categorize the quality of the network.

It's called [network-connection-class](https://github.com/facebook/network-connection-class).

Comment: That seems like a viable option. I should also make it clear that by "would use any available data." I meant that it would use mobile data instead of wifi connection if available, which would give me false results, unless there is a way to ping through the wifi connection.

Comment: As long as you are connected to WiFi, your requests will attempt to use that connection so you can send ping requests without worrying about using mobile data.

Comment: But then what if WiFi is connected but not working and mobile data is active and working? Is there a way to identify if response comes from WiFi connection or to restrict ping through WiFi only?

Comment: Use `ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo()` to see what the default network will be.  So even if WiFi does not have connectivity, if `getActiveNetworkInfo()` returns WiFi as the default connection, it will be used (or attempted).